# How should I approach testing controllers in AJAX Rails 3 application?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

Here's the thing, I have `Article` and `Category` models, where obviously article belongs to one category.

I want to have the option of creating a new category in the new Article's form, so I decided to use AJAX. The form looks very simple.

```
<%= form_for @category, :method => :post, :remote => true do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>

    <p class="button"><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

same as the `CategoriesController`

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :js

  def create
    @category = Category.new(params[:category])
    @saved = @category.save
  end
end
```

and `create.js.coffee` view template

```
if <%= @saved %>
  $('#category_name').val ''
  new_option = $("<option value='<%= @category.id %>'><%= @category.name %></option>").attr('selected', 'selected')
  $('select#article_category_id').append(new_option).focus()
else
  alert "Category already exists"
  $('#category_name').val('').focus()
```

I've been using integration testing via request specs, [as described in Ryan Bates' screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara), which seems to work just fine, e.g.

```
it "supports js", :js => true do
  visit new_article_path
  fill_in "category_name", :with => "foobar"
  click_button "Add category"
  page.should have_content("foobar")
end
```

The thing is, the controller is responding with a `.js.coffe` template, so I can't really have view specs. **Should I even bother with testing controllers when I have request specs in place?**

And second part of the question. **Is it a good practice to user `.js.coffee` templates as a response from a controller?** Shouldn't I just return a http status code or some JSON, and handle all of that on the client side, instead of generating JavaScript to execute on each response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Request spec is here to test the result of your js. So you should test your controller to be sure it returns the proper values to your `js.coffee`

2) This is really a matter of taste. I really prefer using json + client side js: it's more scalable. But Rails templates could give the impression to have more organized code.